# iPad safari mobile: How can I make one frame pinch-to-zoom while the other remains un-zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

My problem is simple: I need a header ( not `<hr/>`) to remain "docked" at the top of the iPad mobile safari browser viewport when a user pans or zooms the main content of the page. I have scoured the internet, and have found only a few clunky js frameworks.

The iScroll framework claims this cabability, but as you can see from their demo, the user experience is quite poor: http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/zoom/
(jumpy, often hangs for seconds at a time, etc.)

Since the native zoom/pan capabilities are quite good, I thought the best solution would be to make a frameset where one is made user-zoomable with a meta tag, and the other non-zoomable. Like this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes|no" />`

Unfortunately, this did not work. I fear it may not be possible to do it this way...

Someone has asked the same question on an apple forum, of course they have not answered:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3774841?start=0&tstart=0

---

I am open to any suggestions about how to accomplish this behavior.

Assuming the frameset approach is impossible: I would prefer not to include a clunky js framework. (although i'm already using jQuery and jQuery UI) I really just need to resize and reposition a div based on viewport orientation, scroll position and zoom level.